# Extending A Laravel View In A Parent Folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

My view folder structure looks like this

```
+ views
  + user
    -login.blade.php 
  -layout.blade.php
  -header.blade.php
  -footer.blade.php
```

I want `login.blade.php` (which is in the user folder) to extend the `layout.blade.php` (which is in the views folder) but it is not working. I have tried the following statements but doesn't work::

```
@extends("views.layout")
@extends(".views.layout")
@extends("app.views.layout")
```

Can someone tell me what am doing wrong.

thanks

Comment: Have you try `@extends('layout')`?

Comment: The root path for the view is already `app/views` so you don't need to include that in the view name.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick answers. it works now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *views* directory is the main one, so you shouldn't declare it in the path. You could simply use:

```
@extends("layout")
```

Comment: Hi. How to extend if the layout folder is in resources not in resources/views ?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use `layout` without anything in front. All views are absolute to the view path.

```
@extends('layout')
```

Answer (score 1):

You will always extend/ include files from the views root. 
Just use `@extends("layout")`